# Why needed to increase dn_max_connection_for_internal_service when adding confignode in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone seen this error report in Apache IoTDB? When adding ConfigNode in IoTDB, seed_confignode field showed this error.

```
you need to increase dn_max_connection_for_internal_service.
```

I don't know why I need to increase this parameter and how this parameter related to adding ConfigNode action. Anyone can explain this to me?